# Jquery callback on each method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, click

I'm facing little problem with the jQuery each() method :

```
jQuery(":button[attributeFoo=\"bar\"]").each(function( index ) {
  jQuery( this ).click();
});

location.reload(true);
```

Here, the first instruction get a list of html button and click() on each of them (thus start an ajax action).
And then i want reload the page. But here the page reload before all ajax click() request are done.

What's the best way to wait for all click ajax exchange are done before reload the page ?

Comment: A hacky approach would be `setTimeout(location.reload, 5000);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as follows:

Everything you set inside the callback function will be executed while the process is still ongoing. But, the next sentence:

```
location.reload(true);
```

(which is outside the callback that "waits" for results) is executed right after the jquery statement, without caring if this statement ended or not.

One solution that could work for you:

```
var elements=jQuery(":button[attributeFoo=\"bar\"]");
var total=elements.length;

jQuery(elements).each(function( index, elem ) {
  jQuery(elem).click();
  if(index == total-1) 
    location.reload(true);
});

console.log("show before reload")
```

So, it reloads the page, once the last element has been processed (clicked) inside the callback. Mind that the message "show before reload" will appear before the page refresh.

Comment: The result is the same :( The page reloads after the last click() called but severals precedent click() may not done yet.

Comment: You mean that the click on each element triggers another action that should be completed? --> (the code you show triggers a click, which is one single synchronous action) Are the not clicked elements doing more actions you need to wait for?

Comment: Yes exactly sorry to not was clear on that. I think the only way to do here is the "hacky" approach provide by Jonas.W. But i will accept your response who is perfect in case when click is realy sync.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing all your ajax requests on button click to **synchronous** that way until the ajax requests on button click are not completed your page will not reload.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but it's not my code who is called on click action, i can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

In That Case,

You can check number of requests with server and if it is 0 then reload the page.

```
jQuery(":button[attributeFoo=\"bar\"]").each(function( index ) {
    jQuery( this ).click();
});

while(jQuery.active != 0)
{
}

location.reload(true);
```